# Infer the key type of the array object

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have the next example

```js
type C = [
    {name: 'a'},
    {name: 'b'},
    {name: 'c'},
]
```

And I want to infer a new type `SomeType` based on the type `C` described above like this

```js
const a: SomeType<C> = {
    a: () => {},
    b: () => {},
    c: () => {},
}
```

And so that there is a check of all keys. The following example must be invalid

```js
const a: SomeType<C> = {
    a: () => {},
    b: () => {},
    // Error. "c" is not defined
}
```

I have tried to solve my problem like in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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), but my solution doesn't check presence all keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
type SomeType<T extends { [k: number]: { name: string } }> =
    Record<T[number]['name'], () => void>;
```

It accepts `T` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a type with a numeric [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) (such as an array) whose elements have a `name` property of type `string`.

And it evaluates to a type whose keys are those `string`-assignable `name` properties (using `T[number]['name']`, a series of [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)), and whose value types are a function (I chose `() => void` but you might have a more specific type you care about).  This uses [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to represent an object type with keys of type  `K` and values of types `V`.

Let's try it out:

```
const ports: SomeType<C> = { // error, missing b and c
    a: () => { },
}    

const ports2: SomeType<C> = {
    unknownkey: () => { }, // error, unknown key in object literal 
                           // (note, only errors for object literal)
}

const ports3: SomeType<C> = { // okay
    a: () => { },
    c: () => { },
    b: () => { },
}
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwlC8UDaAoK6oG8oDsCGAthAFxQDkeZUAvgDRobb5GlkBGVdD6ThJ5AY070AuihShIUAMoB7IgBVwEADwKoEAB7AIOACYBnLMgDWpHAFcCbCACcRpXiygHgtgJY4A5jRoA+BG4oACUIAVlbPTUkS2s7ESQyZggyEVooAAoASgQAgDdZdz0-AG5xcJxXKDAI4ANSOUVlFRgAxGwAeg6NW1sI9IJ3AwNPHzYoPH0oASC8Umzc4y5qcRQKqprbOoAmBvkIJUgWtqwgixwTHFkAdwuIEHmc+ADsOigunr7bdPPLm5woCZ7lBPFBZGwAFZhYBQAA27h0tjwsMyshwsJAnwiRgAZhEwZDoXCEXZkVkUCs1miNrUDABmPZNI6tBDGD6yEx4ECzR6LV70DDTXnPJYCjBsYUvGj0FZAA)

Answer (score 1):

You need a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) to map from the array type to your desire type:

```
type SomeType<T extends Array<{ name: string }>> = {
  [P in T[number]['name']]: () => void
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwlC8UDaAoKUDeUB2BDAthAFxQDkupUAvgDRqY4HFkBGlt9WehJpAxuzoBdFClCQoAZQD2hACrgIAHjlQIAD2ARsAEwDOUAIIAnY7hBKuTEnuDGAltgDm1AHyuEmekgAKUR1BySNgArvgsEMZCSKTcEKRCQiQAFACUCB4AbtL2OihUonzS2LZQuCQy8opKMB6IGPTlUGkZDBzoLCnp8B5Y7VB8Xa19dFRAA)